# Chromium always launching in Incognito mode

Tags: robotframework

How can I stop Chromium (RobotFrameWork with Browser Library) stop from running in incognito?

what I try is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Browser

*** Test Cases ***
test1
New Browser     chromium     headless=false     args=["--user-data-dir"]
```

error message is:

```
Error: browserType.launch: Pass userdDataDir parameter to 'browserType.launchPersisentContext(userDataDir, ...)' instead of specifying --user-data-dir argument....
```

but...

how would that look like in .robot framework language so to speak?